# React Router `browserHistory`: Do I have to render on server?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, frontend, flux

I am new to `React` and just learning how routing works. `hashHistory` (`/#/paths/like/this`) works great but `browserHistory` (`/paths/like/this`) look much better. Obviously, `browserHistory` paths do not work right out of the box when I re-open URLs, because the broweser requests `/path/on/server` that does not exist.

The question is: Do I have to use server-side rendering (so called `isomorphic rendering`) in order to use `/nice/paths` and let users open pages directly, or be able to Ctrl+R pages and stay where they are, or there are options to do it keeping just `client-side` rendering?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No you can easily use `client-side` rendering and allow users to use paths like `nice/paths/`.

Since these routes are just a React convenience and does not exist on the server, going directly to them throws an error as the pages simply do not exist. To solve this you should point all your routes to `index.html` (your entry point for the application) in the server and then let React take over to handle the path.

In Express it would be done like this:

```
app.get('*', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/public/index.html')
})
```

For an Apache server this would be the `.htaccess`:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
</IfModule>
```

For other server side languages they have their own methods and this pointing to `index.html` basically works for all SPA frameworks like Angular etc as the logic is the same.

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

**Mrinalmech** gave right answer, I just want to add an example of a config for Nginx:

```
server {

    server_name yourHostName.com;
    listen 80;

    root /path/to/app/folder;
    index index.html;

    location ~ ^[a-zA-Z0-9/_-]+$ {
        rewrite (.*) /index.html last;
    }
}
```